# rails seo url, convert - to spaces

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, url, seo

I have a car model name forte 5-door in my database, i'm routing to the car model page like /:makename/:modelname => some#action

For models like forte 5-door
Url will be like localhost:3000/kia/forte-5-door(optimized for SEO)

in this page i need to query in my controller for model name so 
Here my params[:modelname] => forte-5-door

Model.where(:model_name => params[:modelname])

Doesn't match any model name in my db so page shows error, how to fix this

Comment: why you do this way? although there is ` rails preety url` or `to_param` for seo url

Comment: The URL should be like this site.com/browse-cars/make/modelname so i created a new page and added routes, so i can't use friendly id or pretty url, now i don;t have/use the model just method written inside a controller

Answer (score 0):

I would use this:
https://github.com/norman/friendly_id/blob/master/README.md

It will save you a lot of headaches and works like a charm.